# Why does my select list not translate to another language in Views?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I have a View for **Search in property**, which has many fields and some of them are drop-downs (select lists).

When I switch the language to *Arabic*, everything is translated, but the drop-down is still in English (= default language).

I performed these steps:

- I translated my select list in Manage fields and translate the options there
- then I put them in Manage display to default translated.

But it's not working. Check the image for more details:

[image]

Any ideas about how to solve this problem?

Comment: If this question is about Views (as your own answer seems to indicate), then please include that somehow in your question also.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens so u ask my to change my question to be more clearly  about select list in views ?

Comment: Thank you for taking my advice from some days ago (to improve your question to make it match your answer). Much better now! Though I think you should also mark your own answer as "accepted" (assuming it worked for you). That way it will no longer show up in the "unanswered questions".

Comment: yeah that's right my friend @Pierre.Vriens i will make my answer accepted 
and thanks a lot for your advice dude am fresh in this site .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer for this finally ...

After doing all the steps like the image that I attached before,
you should delete the old FILTER CRITERIA and add the New translated one to make the select list translate :

[image]

After doing so, the select list will be translated.